# Coercion error when passing Boolean argument in graphql-ruby mutation query

Tags: ruby, graphql, graphql-ruby

I have a simple `graphql-ruby` mutation:

```rb
class Mutations::User::Destroy < Mutations::BaseMutation
  argument :confirm, GraphQL::Types::Boolean, required: true
  payload_type GraphQL::Types::Boolean

  def resolve(confirm:)
    true
  end
end
```

The parent module for this mutation is:

```rb
module Mutations
  class BaseMutation < GraphQL::Schema::RelayClassicMutation
  # ....
```

In a spec, I have the following:

```rb
let(:destroy_query) do
  %(
    mutation UserDestroy($input: DestroyInput!) {
      userDestroy(input: $input)
    }
  )
end

it "works" do
  post "/graphql", params: {query: destroy_query, variables: {"input" => {"confirm" => true}}}
```

This query produces an error response from graphql-ruby:

```
{"errors"=>[{"extensions"=>{"problems"=>[{"explanation"=>"Could not coerce value \"true\" to Boolean"...estroyInput! was provided invalid value for confirm (Could not coerce value \"true\" to Boolean)"}]}
```

However, when I tested the query in Apollo Studio, it worked fine. I'm not able to pass the `true` value in the query here. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? I'm considering changing the argument type to something custom, like a `YES` string. But if someone knows of a different approach, I would appreciate the insight. Thank you.

Comment: I find this very useful https://github.com/kashiftufail/graphql_api_nested

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how DestroyInput comes in as being in use.

I would call it this way

```
  %(
    mutation UserDestroy($confirm: Boolean!) {
      userDestroy(confirm: $confirm)
    }
  )
```

```
post '/graphql', params: { query, destory_query, variables: { confirm: true } }
```

You've titled something "DestoryInput", but you never created an attribute type to describe it.  What is being called "DestroyInput?"

Comment: my best guess is that it's `GraphQL::Schema::RelayClassicMutation` that provides some additional sugar, from the doc: `using a single input: argument makes it easy to post whole JSON objects to the mutation using one GraphQL variable ($input) instead of making a separate variable for each argument.`